# jQuery callback issues, it runs just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I am having some issues with a piece of code, I use jQuery's ajax to load search results, because its a list I wanted to style the list, zerbra style, so I have included a callback function. The following works the first time but when I search again it doesn't work (styling).

When I put an alert in the callback function it fires every time, but the styling doesn't work.

**ajax part**

```
  $.post('search.php',{value:val}.function(data){
  // output list

  }).error(function(){
      // error output
  }).success(function(){    
          // callback function. 
          if(typeof options.afterLoad == 'function'){
              options.afterLoad.call(this);
          }                     
  });
```

**the plugin options**

```
  $('#search').search({
      afterLoad: function(){
         $('#results').children('li:odd').addClass('odd');
      }
  });
```

This isn't the complete plugin, but just the parts that matter.

Comment: why just not use css? :nth-child(odd)

Comment: `$.post('search.php',{value:val}function(data){` is not valid syntax

Comment: :nth-child is nice but not supported by all browsers methinks

Comment: that i can do, but i want to know why this isn't working this way, and the callback can contain different stuff

Comment: @deerua `nth-child` psuedoselector does not work in all browsers.

Comment: Is the class not being applied or is it just not styled? Why don't you do this server side?

Comment: Is the syntax error of the missing comma pointed out by @jbabey simply a typo or is it real?

Answer (score 0):

If the callback is executed then I can think on 3 options:

- There is no control with id `results`
- There is no children `li` for `#results`
- Class `odd` doesn't exist or it doesn't containst the style rules you suppose it has (maybe a cache issue?)

Put a `debugger` instruction on the callback and check the `length` of  `$('#results')` and `$('#results').children('li:odd')`

Comment: Well the results have been loaded, so the id excite, the class odd excite, as the first time that i run the script the zebra strippes are visible, but when i hit the submit button agian it doesnt restyle the rows.

Comment: You said "When I put an alert in the callback function it fires every time". If fires everytime but the style is not applying there is an issue on this line `$('#results').children('li:odd').addClass('odd');`. Am I missing something?

Comment: you are correct, that why this is a bit strange, it will fire the callback, but not the styling after the first time(i have tried hiding the list items, that also didn't work)

Comment: @user759235: please add a debugger and check 2 first options I wrote on my answer (for those cases that doesn't work). Just to double check.